# Firebase Tensorflow Lite Model

Tags: firebase, tensorflow, mobile, tensorflow-lite, firebase-machine-learning

I am building a Tensorflow model to predict a certain feature for each user. So, I am making a model for each user of the application. I was wondering how to I upload the Tensorflow lite model to the Firebase in such a way that each user can access the model specific to him/her. For example, let's say there are two users A and B. When A makes a call to firebase, I want to make sure A's model is called and when B uses the app, I want to make sure B's model is called.
Hope that makes sense, Could someone please tell me if there is a way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: If you still using interpreter you have to upload every model in Storage of Firebase project. Then depend on the user u have to download the model and initialize it when u want to use it. Is this solution OK?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different model for each user it wouldn't scale very well if you have a large number of users.

You can use some properties of the user as input in your model, or encode them into some embedding space then use it as part of the input, you can find more info about it here:
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/embeddings/video-lecture

Then you can have a single model that works for all users.